# Why I get more then one window per key in flink session window

Tags: scala, session, apache-flink

My requirements is to check if both begin and success events in a session. I use session window, of course.But it seems there're overlapped windows per key. I've searched online and couldn't know why.

Data format: `myForm(timestamp, roomId, role, sessionId, event)`, for example:

```
myform(1559128942, 123, kid, 37890, begin) # timestamp equals to 2019-05-29 19:22:22.605  
myform(1559128944, 123, kid, 37890, success) # timestamp equals to 2019-05-29 19:22:24.844  
myform(1559129977, 456, kid, 38239, begin) # timestamp equals to 2019-05-29 19:39:37  
...
```

session may have only one pair of begin and success events, may also several pairs of events of begin and sucess events.
event may arrive late, and is allowed late to maxinum 3 minutes.

My key is `roomId` + `role` + `sessionId` like '123_kid_37890', `seesionGap` is 60s

```scala
// use event time
env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime)
val stream = ... // from kafka, steam of myform
val sessionStream = stream
    .assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(new MyFormEventWatermarks(0L))
    .keyBy(mf => mf.roomId + "_" + mf.role + "_" + mf.sessionId)
 .window(EventTimeSessionWindows.withGap(Time.milliseconds(60 * 1000L))      
.allowedLateness(Time.minutes(3))
.apply(myFormWindowFunction)

//MyFormEventWatermarks is :
class MyFormEventWatermarks[T <: AbstractForm](dely: Long) extends AssignerWithPeriodicWatermarks[T] {

  private var currentMaxTimestamp = Long.MinValue
  val maxOutOfOrderness = dely

  @transient
  var waterMark : Watermark = null

  override def getCurrentWatermark: Watermark = {
    if (currentMaxTimestamp == Long.MinValue){
      waterMark = new Watermark(Long.MinValue)
      waterMark
    }
    else{
      waterMark = new Watermark(currentMaxTimestamp - maxOutOfOrderness)
      waterMark
    }
  }

  override def extractTimestamp(data: T, previousElementTimestamp: Long): Long = {
    val timestamp = data.timestamp
    currentMaxTimestamp = Math.max(timestamp, currentMaxTimestamp)
    timestamp
  }


}


//window func is 
class myFormWindowFunction extends RichWindowFunction ... {
    ...
    override def apply(key: String, window: TimeWindow, input: Iterable[myForm], out: Collector[List[myForm]]): Unit = {
        println("window is " + window.getStart() + "-" + window.getEnd() + "|" + data.tostring)

    }
    ...

}
```

In method `apply` of `myFormWindowFunction`, results of `println` like:

```
// like this session data:
myform(1559128942, 123, kid, 37890, begin) # timestamp equals to 2019-05-29 19:22:22.605  
myform(1559128944, 123, kid, 37890, success) # timestamp equals to 2019-05-29 19:22:24.844
```

I got a window of `2019-05-29 19:22:22.605- 2019-05-29 19:23:22.605`,data is `myform(1559128942, 123, kid, 37890, begin)`, then I got a second window of `2019-05-29 19:22:22.605 - 2019-05-29 19:23:24.844`and data is `myform(1559128942, 123, kid, 37890, begin), myform(1559128944, 123, kid, 37890, success)`.
It looks like window initalize to (2019-05-29 19:22:22.605, 2019-05-29 19:23:22.605) and (2019-05-29 19:22:24.844, 2019-05-29 19:23:24.844), and `onMerge` method merged but not 'droped' window (2019-05-29 19:22:22.605, 2019-05-29 19:23:22.605). I've looked up the source function of `EventTimeSessionWindows` and examples of flink session window, and still don't known where program goes wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default behavior for events assigned to a window during the allowed lateness interval is to trigger the window as each late event is added to the window -- but it's also possible to implement a custom trigger that fires at the expiration of the allowed lateness, either instead of, or in addition to the other firings.

Note that with session windows, an event that arrives late may cause a late merge.

You may want to think about the tradeoffs between the watermarking delay and the allowed lateness. Because your watermark delay is zero, you are likely to have quite a few late events (every time the event stream isn't perfectly in order by timestamp). If instead, for example, you used 3 minutes as the watermark delay and set allowed lateness to zero, then you would produce the same final results, but with no late triggerings and no late merges -- but with 3 minutes of latency before the initial triggering of each window.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, David. Indeed, I've used 3minutes as  the watermark delay instead and dropped `.allowedLateness(Time.minutes(3))`, problem is solved. One more question: Does dropping `.allowedLateness(Time.minutes(3))`  equal to `.allowedLateness(Time.minutes(0))`. I looked up to know the winodw would be fired again  when  window + allowedLateness arrives, so I wonder if the window is still triggered  the second time even if allowed lateness is set to 0.

Comment: Yes, dropping allowedLateness is the same as setting it to 0, and the windows will not be triggered a second time. (Furthermore, given 3 minutes as the watermark delay events more than 3 minutes out of order will be late, and will be dropped unless you collect them with a side output.)

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problem, I made a misunderstanding of allowedLateness. When it's used, window is saved and when window  + allowedLateness time arrives, window will be triggered again.